# jQUery context menu on left click

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I am using [jQuery context menu plugin by Chris Domigan](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/) to appy a context menu. This is how it works:

```
$('#contacts tbody tr').contextMenu('myMenu1', {
    bindings: {
        'copy': function(t) {
             alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Copy');
         },

        'delete': function(t) {
             alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Delete');
        }
    },             
});
```

Now I want this context menu to appear on left click instead of right click. I can not find an option in the doc. Any ideas how to do that? Do I have to modify the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the title on the source

> ContextMenu - jQuery plugin for **right-click** context menus

Also in the doc there's no info about how to change the kind of click. I think the only thing you could do is to extend that code to work with the basic "click()" too ;)

Answer (score 10):

I know it's old, but i'll answer it anyways ;)

If you want to call ContextMenu on left-click, just change the line:

```
$(this).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
```

into this:

```
$(this).bind('click', function(e) {
```

But if You want to capture more events to display ContextMenu, You can add event names after spacebar, according to jQuery .bind() reference.

For instance, if You want to display the menu on **left and right click** just change the line into this:

```
$(this).bind('contextmenu click', function(e) {
```

Comment: @yonox writes: `$(this).bind('contextmenu click', function(e) {`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you would need to change the code. You need to change this line:

```
 $(this).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
```

into this

```
 $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Manela, thanks for your snippet (spent hours at this point)

Also, in my project I want to support both right and left click.
(Maybe someone would need that)
To do this you change your code to:

```
$(this).bind('click contextmenu', function(e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

i know that this is far too late for me to say this.

new contextjs plugin using 'on' instead of bind, because 'on' can define selector like this:

```
$(document)on('contextmenu','selector',function(e){
```

i use this to define my 'left' or 'right' :

```
if(type === 'right'){
    $(document).on('contextmenu', selector, function (e) {
    ....}
else{
    $(document).on('click', selector, function (e) {
    ....}
```