# how to call jquery contextmenu on left-click?

Tags: php, jquery, html, contextmenu

I am using this contextmenu plugin: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

DEMO: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/contextMenu/demo/

SOURCE-CODE: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/contextMenu/demo/jquery.contextMenu.js

DEFAULT CALL:

```
$("#myDiv").contextMenu({
                    menu: 'myMenu'
                },
                    function(action, el, pos) {
                    alert(
                        'Action: ' + action + '\n\n' +
                        'Element ID: ' + $(el).attr('id') + '\n\n' + 
                        'X: ' + pos.x + '  Y: ' + pos.y + ' (relative to element)\n\n' + 
                        'X: ' + pos.docX + '  Y: ' + pos.docY+ ' (relative to document)'
                        );
                });
```

I want to call this context menu on a left click rather than a right click, how can I achieve this ?
or any other plugin suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQUery context menu on left click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725281/jquery-context-menu-on-left-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a regular click handler:

```
$("#myDiv").on('click', function() {
    $(this).contextmenu(...)
})
```

Comment: That will only attach contextmenu() function to #MyDiv when I left-click. The function itself is listening to right-click.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the source code, looking for the following codes:

**if( evt.button == 2 ) {**...

According to W3C its values should be:

Left button = 0,

Middle button = 1,

Right button = 2,

According to Microsoft its values should be:

Left button = 1,

Middle button = 4,

Right button = 2,

You may change the value depending on what you need.